# RHEL 5.8 [Oracle] too long to shutdown

Tags: oracle, rhel5, oracle-11g

We are using Oracle database on a machine running RHEL 5.8.
Every month we restart our servers (including this one) however this one takes too long to shutdown. Last time took it 40 minutes.
This was the last two lines on screen while waiting for the shutdown:

```
The Oracle base has been set to /opt/oracle
Processing Database instance "ORCL": log file /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/shutdown.log
```

This step here takes all the time. After this the shutdown process just fine and in reasonable time. Is this normal?

Thank you!

Comment: Might the contents of /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/shutdown.log have anything helpful? What does RedHat or Oracle support have to say?

Comment: Oracle in my country don't really have the best support. You leave a message and they might call you back. I just checked the log and it doesn't say much. It just states the time that the shutdown was initiated and that the Database Instance was shutdown!

Comment: 'shu abort' will just drop dead, 'shu immediate' will rollback any uncommited trans and go down. 'shu normal' will wait for all trans to finish. Can take 40 minutes.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt Thank you. I will look into those commands. Still waiting answer from Oracle!

Answer (score 0):

1. be sure that all your applications are stopped (not using the database anymore and leaving active connections, connections pools, connected users etc.)
2. if you don't want to wait, you can kill all remaining sessions in your database (via SQL queries), you can find some scripts.
3. finally, shutdown your instance using "shutdown immediate"
4. you can then shutdown your listener, ASM instance (if you have one), and reboot your server

if active sessions are still there, or anything of that sort, it might take a while (e.g backups, locks, stats generation etc.)